# API for crawled sites?

Tags: api, indexing, web-crawler, scrapy

Was just wondering, does Google or any other company offer an API that allows you to receive crawled links? I want to filter the links with .txt extensions and possibly another additional extension only.

If not, how would I go about crawling/indexing pages but refining it to my chosen extensions only? I also don't want to cross any legal battles, so would I have to comply to robots.txt? And also would I be needing large a database to just crawl the contents of these files? Im wanting to crawl random links (with my chosen extensions), with a starting point at DMOZ.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a particular term to search for in the .txt extensions, you can use Bing search API (https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search) or Yahoo (developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/). But you have limitations on the the number of results you get & you have to pay huge price for it.

But if you want text files in random links, you can build your own search engine with nutch. You can configure nutch to crawl particular file extension.

www.building-blocks.com/thinking/building-a-search-engine-with-nutch-and-solr-in-10-minutes/

stackoverflow.com/questions/8971886/nutch-how-to-crawl-a-specific-file-type